# VirtualBox imported VM - VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED - VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: virtualbox, import, export

On VirtualBox, I've exported a Ubuntu Server VM (File \ Export Appliance) and tried to imported it on a different machine. every thing went well with export and import. But, when I start the imported VM, I get this VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED error VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND.

Its quite weird. If I ditch the Import process and straight away create a new VM and use the exported VMDK, it works fine!!

Both machines are using the same version of VirtualBox (3.2.4 r62467)

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I found this same issue, OS X host exported to a Windows XP host. Both VirtualBox 3.2.6 r63112. Perhaps it is a bug that should be filed?

Workaround - create a new VM and import the VMDK manually.

http://blog.anuragg.com/2012/10/vhdx-to-vhd-conversion.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the settings were imported for the appliance, so I changed the settings to match the new computer (1 cpu instead of 2, and less memory).

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by a known bug in older versions of VirtualBox. See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7251 for details.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same error code (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND), but with a different error description after editing `VirtualBox VMs/<name of vm>/<name of vm>.vbox`:

> NAT#0: configuration query for "GuestPort" int failed (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND)
>   Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND)

It turns out that the name of the forwarding rule should certainly not contain any parentheses or slashes (as shown below). So, when you set a forwarding rule, use a name that consists of spaces, letters or numbers to be safe.

---

For example, the following does **not** work (VM refused to start up with previous error message):

```
...
<NAT>
  <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
  <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
  <Forwarding name="HTTP/8088" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="1080" guestport="80"/>
  <Forwarding name="HTTPS" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="1443" guestport="443"/>
  <Forwarding name="SSH (2022)" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="2022" guestport="22"/>
</NAT>
```

After removing `/`, `(` and `)` from the vbox file, the error message goes away and the VM boots again:

```
<NAT>
  <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
  <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
  <Forwarding name="HTTP" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="1080" guestport="80"/>
  <Forwarding name="HTTPS" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="1443" guestport="443"/>
  <Forwarding name="SSH on port 2022" proto="1" hostip="127.0.0.1" hostport="2022" guestport="22"/>
</NAT>
```

<sub>This post does not answer the question, but this question was one of the few pages I found when I Googled for a solution to my problem.</sub>