# VirtualBox 5.0.6, unable to start single VM after network configuration

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding, nat

I've installed `VirtualBox 5.0.6` on `Windows 10 64bit`, and configured and installed a guest VM with Debian Jessi. Everything works fine at this point.

Then I configured two port forwarding rules:
[port forwarding rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YzmM.png)

One called `ssh` the other one called `tcp/8080`.

At this point, everything still works. But, after restarting the host OS, I was no longer able to run the VM with the port forwarding rules.

I got the following error message:

`NAT#0: configuration query for "GuestPort" int failed (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND) 
Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_CFGM_VALUE_NOT_FOUND)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer to another question with a different erreor message solved the problem:

> It turns out that the name of the forwarding rule should certainly not contain any parentheses or slashes (as shown below). So, when you set a forwarding rule, use a name that consists of spaces, letters or numbers to be safe.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/696704/166173)